# How to use window.location with randomized objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I've made a site that randomizes HTML videos or images just to practice my javascript.

I am trying to make it so that each time a video is randomized the URL location will change to represent the new video, this way users would be able to link directly to a video that was randomized.

Currently it only displays a static url that does not change whenever content is loaded.

Here is the obligatory codepen

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/H0BB5/pen/zxZjgj)

```
 function chooseRandomVideoFromList() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentList.length);
  var video = currentList[i];
  var $video = $('video');



  // clear
  $video.html('');

  // <source src="" type="">

  video.sources.forEach(function (source) {
    var $source = $('<source>').attr('type', source.type).attr('src', source.src);
    $video.append($source);
  });
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, i've read the documentation and I am still stumped  :S

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly write on the window.location.href property, but you may change your sites url with the html5 history api and pushstate.

Example:

```
history.pushState({}, "Stackoverflow", "http://stackoverflow.com");
```

This should work in all modern browsers, see: http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate

More information on this topic could be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Though keep in mind you need also to listen on popstate events if you want the users to be able to use their browsers back and forward buttons. Also your server side code needs to handle the urls.

If you need to support older browsers or don't want the server side to be involved you could set the window.location.hash property instead which does not change the url itself but let you change the hash part of the current url, for example:

```
window.location.hash = "uri=stackoverflow.com";
```

This way you might store the Index of the video currently shown. When loading the page you might want to check if there's a value in "window.location.hash" and if it is a valid index for your videoFiles. If so you should play that video.

Example (insert in your starting code):

```
 if (window.location.hash !== "") {
    showSpecificVideoFromList(window.location.hash);
 }
```

And this one in your chooseRandomVideoFromList:

```
 window.location.hash=i;
```

Then implement your showSpecificVideoFromList in order to show the given index (and check for validity)

Comment: Hey jbrosi, thanks for the response. 
I actually asked this same question but if I could use html push state for this a few days ago here on stack and was told that I wasn't able to. 
Here is a link to that post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27973275/how-to-use-window-history-pushstate-with-multiple-video-locations?noredirect=1#comment44339644_27973275

Comment: Ah ok I think I missunderstood what you were planning to do... I updated my answer

Comment: Hy Jbrosi, I think I am almost where I need to be. Thanks so much with the help but I cant seem to be getting it to work on my end. Do you think you would be able to implement what you're saying on codpen? I provided a new link in my post. 

Thanks again, Ill be sure to upvote you.